# Spring Boot Application with Spring Batch not Running Jobs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have spring boot application I created [from here at spring's site](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/). I'm tampering with it and have basically duplicated it into two jobs, as I'm creating a bigger application that will be structured this way. Nothing is running though and I know it's most likely something small I'm missing.

If I stuff everything into one package just like the tutorial, it works fine, but if I extract the `Application.java` out into its own package, it seems to not acknowledge the other two packages. Even with passing through `-Dspring.batch.job.names=myJob`.

This is all there is to my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Running...");

    }
}
```

The project structure looks like:

```
\---main
    +---java
    |   +---app
    |   |       Application.java
    |   |       
    |   +---job1
    |   |       Job1BatchConfiguration.java
    |   |       Job1JobCompletionNotificationListener.java
    |   |       Job1Person.java
    |   |       Job1PersonItemProcessor.java
    |   |       
    |   \---job2
    |           Job2BatchConfiguration.java
    |           Job2JobCompletionNotificationListener.java
    |           Job2Person.java
    |           Job2PersonItemProcessor.java
    |           
    \---resources
            sample-data-2.csv
            sample-data.csv
            schema-all.sql
```

Again, if I put `Application.java` into either the `job1` or `job2` package, that job will execute, if I stuff all of them into a single package and pass through `-Dspring.batch.job.names=job1,job2`, it will execute both (or one if I want). But how can I get this command to work when the `Application.java` is at a different package scope? Is there a way to make it see those?

---

EDIT: So it looks like I can annotate my `Application.java` with

```
@Import({Job1BatchConfiguration.class, Job1JobCompletionNotificationListener.class, Job2BatchConfiguration.class, Job2JobCompletionNotificationListener.class})
```

But if I exceed more than even three jobs, this solution seems to get really sloppy. Any way to condense this functionality for the jobs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Application` class add the annotation of `@ComponentScan` pointing at a higher package:

```
@ComponentScan("app")
```

or alternatively you can include multiple packages as well:

```
@ComponentScan("app.job1", "app.job2")
```

This annotation scans the packages and registers not only `@Component` or other beans but also `@Configuration` classes too.

Comment: Ah, hello again. I knew it was something small I was missing, totally over looked that functionality. I left the office so I will most definitely try this when I'm back and I'm sure I'll find that my problem will be solved. Thanks again for your help mate

Answer (score 2):

My problem was solved putting my main class in package root of my struct.

Using the example showed, the location of Application is:

```
\---main
    +---java
    |   +---Application.java (Change location this file to package root)
    |   |       
    |   +---job1
    |   |       Job1BatchConfiguration.java
    |   |       Job1JobCompletionNotificationListener.java
    |   |       Job1Person.java
    |   |       Job1PersonItemProcessor.java
    |   |       
    |   \---job2
    |           Job2BatchConfiguration.java
    |           Job2JobCompletionNotificationListener.java
    |           Job2Person.java
    |           Job2PersonItemProcessor.java
    |           
    \---resources
            sample-data-2.csv
            sample-data.csv
            schema-all.sql
```